# abstract data types in algorithms

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, adt

> The data structures that we use in applications often contain a great
>   deal of information of various types, and certian pieces of
>   information may be belong to multiple independent data structures. For
>   example, a file of personnel data may contain records with names,
>   addresses, and various other pieces of information about employees;
>   and each record may need to belong to one data structure for searching
>   for particular employees, to another data structure for answering
>   statistical queries, and so forth.
>
> Despite this diverstiy and complexity, a large class of computing
>   applications involve generic manipulation of data objects, and need
>   access to the information associated with them for a limited number of
>   specific reasons. Many of the manipulations that are required are a
>   natural outgrowth of basic computational procedures, so they are
>   needed in broad variety of applications.

Above text is described in context of abstract data types by Robert Sedwick in Algorithms in C++.

My questions is what does author mean by first paragraph in above text?

Comment: it means that data structure are complex and may refer to other data structures and maybe more localized information

Comment: Is that a real quote from a book, or the result of Google Translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if one knew what the conclusion of all this is, but from what I gather:

Employee record:

```
Name Address Phone-Number      Salary Bank-Account      Department Superior
```

As you can see, the employee database has information for each employee that by itself is "subdivided" into chunks of more-or-less independent pieces: the contact information for an employee has little or nothing to do with the department he works in, or the salary he gets.

EDIT: As such, depending on what kind of stuff needs to be done, different parts of this larger record need to be looked at, possibly in different fashion. If you want to know how much salary you're paying in total you'll need to do different things than for looking up the phone number of an employee.

Answer (score 2):

Data structures are combinations of data storage and algorithms that work on those organisations of data to provide implementations of certain operations (searching, indexing, sorting, updating, adding, etc) with particular constraints. These are the building blocks (in a black box sense) of information representation in software. At the most basic level, these are things like queues, stacks, lists, hash maps/associative containers, heaps, trees etc.

Different data structures have different **tradeoffs**. You have to use the right one in the right situation. This is key.

In this light, you can use multiple (or "compound") data structures in parallel that allow different ways of querying and operating on the same logical data, hence filling each other's tradeoffs (strengths/weaknesses e.g. one might be presorted, another might be good at tracking changes, but be more costly to delete entries from, etc), usually at the cost of some extra overhead since those data structures will need to be kept synchronised with each other.

Answer (score 0):

An object may be a part of another object/structure, and the association is not unique; one object may be a part of multiple different structures, depending on context.

Say, there's a corporate employee John. His "employee record" will appear in the list of members of his team, in the salaries list, in the security clearances list, parking places assignment etc.

Not all data contained within his "employee record" will be needed in all of these contexts. His expertise fields are not necessary for parking place allotment, and his marital status should not play a role in meeting room assignment - separate subsystems and larger structures his entry is a part of don't require all of the data contained within his entry, just specific parts of it.